# SOAP ui giving multiple response from one request. (Trying to create Mock services)

Tags: java, soapui

I am facing a strange issue. Also I am new in soapui.
I am trying to create a Mock service using WSDL. I created request as well as a response in soapui. Problem is whenever I click from the request window to get the response, one by one i am getting all the responses (I have created 2 requests and 2 responses). I googled a lot but did not get through this issue. Please help me in this.
In a nutshell : "How can I select the right response based on a condition ?"

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
I wrote a script:

```
def alert = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
def req = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent)

if(req=='CI'){
    alert.showInfoMessage("111111 !  "+req);
    return "CityResponse"
}else if(req=='ST'){
    alert.showInfoMessage("2222222 !  "+req);
    return "StateResponse"
}else{
    alert.showInfoMessage("333333 !  "+req);
    return "CountryResponse"
}
```